# Why is Twitch OAuth redirecting to a link with query strings separated by ‘#’?

Tags: express, oauth, authorization, twitch, twitch-api

I am creating a user login with the OAuth. Everything seems to work fine but Twitch redirect URI is messed up by the # where ? has to be.

My redirect URI:

```
https://localhost:7681/authorize
```

URI Twitch redirects to:

```
https://localhost:7681/authorize#access_token=43r99nhmxhvpckr4zrtb0sbx1q6tdg&scope=user%3Aread%3Aemail&state=%24%7Bdata.uid%7D&token_type=bearer
```

I already tried adding a trailing slash, nothing changed.

Did someone else encounter such behavior?

Comment: Because that's the way the Twitch developers implemented it. But seriously, you can extract these values **on the client side** using code like `new URLSearchParams(window.location.hash.slice(1))`.

Answer (score 2):

> you requested a token for type token instead of a token of type code
>
> token aka Implicit Auth is for client side apps and will generte and
> return a access token via location hash
>
> https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/getting-tokens-oauth#implicit-grant-flow
>
> “Normal” oAuth, aka " Authorization code grant" will return a ?code
> that is to be exchanged for an access token.
>
> https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/getting-tokens-oauth#authorization-code-grant-flow
>
> Essentially your <a href triggered the wrong token flow
>
> Additionally you should never post generated access tokens publically.
> Since someone can take it and abuse it or just revoke it. Or in this
> case acquire your private email address.

https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/why-is-twitch-oauth-redirecting-to-a-link-with-query-strings-separated-by/37976/2